# Dockerizing any Angular SPA app that runs in node

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

There are a lot of Angular 2+ templates (for example http://coreui.io/) that run fine in Node, simply by:

```
npm install
npm start
```

However, making them run in Docker container is a challenge.  I tried the standard approach to creating `dockerfile` but this doesn't work

Should there be a simple way of dockerizing any app that runs on Node with?

What am I missing?

This is what my dockerfile looks like (generated by `yo docker`):

```
    FROM node:latest
    WORKDIR /src
    EXPOSE 4200
    ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
    COPY . /src
    RUN npm install
```

Comment: which template you used

Comment: what error you are getting when u create a `dockerfile`

Comment: docker doesn't return any error

Comment: so is it creating a `dockerfile` or not?

Comment: I create the dockerfile manually, then I Build an image from a Dockerfile,  Then I do docker run -

Comment: See if you can get this to work:
http://coreui.io/

Comment: Post your dockerfile and describe what you're experiencing.  "Doesn't work" isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing i would suggest, don't use `node:latest`. what version of node do you normally run? specify that version.

you probably need to create the `/src` folder

and you should also change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`

```
FROM node:7.9
RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src

# cache the node modules for faster re-builds
COPY ./package.json /src
RUN npm install

COPY . /src

EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

this should cover the most basic of node apps.

---

things do get complex quickly, though. if you need more info on building out a proper dockerfile, i have a full course on docker with nodejs: https://sub.watchmecode.net/guides/build-node-apps-in-docker/

Comment: Thanks Derick, it's an honor.  Been reading your stuff since backbone marionette :)